# Client program can't connect to server hosted on 0.0.0.0

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I made a client program and a server program

Hosting and connecting to 127.0.0.1:23000 works:
[hosting and connecting to 127.0.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NscJX.png)

but hosting and connecting to 0.0.0.0:23000 doesn't:
[hosting and connecting to 0.0.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DpDd.png)

If I host a server on 0.0.0.0:23000 and connect to it using telnet, it works. But not if I use my client, why?

Here's me connecting to my server which was hosted on 0.0.0.0:23000 with telnet: [telnet connecting to 0.0.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ9eE.png)

I made it so that if localhost is the input IP, the IPAddress object is assigned IPAddress.Any, why does it not work?

Here's the exception in text:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context 0.0.0.0:23000
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
   at SocketClient.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a wildcard IP.  A server can *bind* to it for listening (ie, to listen on all available local interfaces), but a client can't *connect* to it.

Comment: Yeah so basically when its listening on 0.0.0.0, its listening on the loopback IP which is 127.0.0.1 in my case, right?

Comment: Yes, listening on 0.0.0.0 will be listening on the loopback IP, amongst others. A client will be able to connect to *any* IP that belongs to the server machine.

Comment: That makes this even clearer, thank you

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `0.0.0.0` can be as target address. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419880/connecting-to-ip-0-0-0-0-succeeds-how-why

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this I've realized why it works with telnet but not with my client: Apparently, when a server is hosted on 0.0.0.0 a client can't connect to 0.0.0.0 but it can connect to the server through 127.0.0.1, so to connect to the server which was hosted on 0.0.0.0 you would need to connect to 127.0.0.1 because that's the loopback IP.

This is what telnet does, when you type in "localhost" as the IP, it connects to 127.0.0.1, not 0.0.0.0. This can be seen when the telnet client connects and it's IP endpoint is shown on the server.

Here's me getting my client to connect to my server which was hosted on 0.0.0.0: [connecting to server hosted on 0.0.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP6dx.png)